# error: expected an identifier

Tags: c, random, identifier

I am getting the following error using Visual Studio:

41 IntelliSense: expected an identifier

I have no idea what this is trying to say and any help would be appreciated! :D

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int
main(void)
{
         long long d;
     long long p;

     //Ask for numbers of days as long as input is not between 28 and 31

    do
    {
    printf("How may days are in your month?\n");
    d = GetInt();
    }
    while (d<28 || d>31);


    //Ask for numbers of pennies for day 1 as long as input is negative



    printf("How many pennies do you have");
    do
    {
        p = GetInt();
    }
    while ("p<0");


    //Sum up the pennies, pennies = (pennies*2)*2..*2

    int 1;
    for (i=0; i<= d-1; i++);
        {

            p=p*pow(2,i);
        }       
    printf("%lld\n", p);
    return 0;
}`
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
int 1;
for (i=0; i<= d-1; i++);
```

Here you have `int 1;` so the compiler is looking for a variable name such as `int x = 1;`
Now the for loop, remove that `;` from the end

inside the `main` the first two lines you have are

```
long long d;
long long p;
```

Here `long` is a type, so change those lines to

```
long d;
long p;
```

At the end of you file i see `}'`, here remove the `'` character

In addition, I can see you have `while ("p<0");` as the while condition, here `"p<0"` is a string, you might want to change it to `p<0`.

Answer (score 2):

You also probably want to replace

```
while ("p<0");
```

with

```
while(p<0);
```

(without the quotes).